# Where can I find the source code of Java's PKIXValidator implementation?

Tags: java, x509certificate, pkix

I want to extend the certificate validation algorithm, or modularize it, so that I can pick which validations I can skip. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I was hoping I could inherit from Java Sun's implementation of PKIX.

However, I can't find the source code. Apparently it's an engine class, and a validator is obtained with `getInstance("PKIX")`. The closes I came to find was `PKIXValidator` in `$JAVA_HOME\lib\src.zip\java.base\sun\security\validator\PKIXValidator`.

I feel this isn't the right file though, as the class itself has the following method:

```java
private X509Certificate[] doValidate(X509Certificate[] chain,
            PKIXBuilderParameters params) throws CertificateException {

            CertPathValidator validator = CertPathValidator.getInstance("PKIX");
            CertPath path = factory.generateCertPath(Arrays.asList(chain));
            certPathLength = chain.length;
            PKIXCertPathValidatorResult result =
                (PKIXCertPathValidatorResult)validator.validate(path, params);

            return toArray(path, result.getTrustAnchor());
    }
```

As this class doesn't implement the `validate()` method, I assume there's another file which actually validates the certificate. And I don't mean only the signature, I mean KeyUsage, Extensions, correct Issuer/Subject, the whole package.

So, to sum up. I am looking for the implementations to check correct KeyUsage, Subject and Issuer, Critical Extensions, etc.